# opencv pencil sketch works without linear dodge

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying a pencil sketch effect in OpenCV. The post I was reading applied linear dodge on the image, with blurred (negative image) as mask to obtain the effect.

```
inv=255-img
blur=cv2.GaussianBlur(inv,(21,21),0,0)
res=cv2.divide(img,255-blur,scale=256)
```

but I found out that the effect can be achieved without inverting the image(results at the bottom, left -with inverse and right without inverse)
I did this.

```
blur2=cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(21,21),0,0)
res = cv2.divide(img,blur2,scale=256)
```

I also read in some StackOverflow answer, and they also suggested the first approach.
I wanted to know why it is required to apply blur to the negative if we are converting back to the original? 
Thank you for taking out your time to answer the question.

[image]
Instructions to convert image to sketch in the book "opencv with python blueprints".

1. Convert the colour image to grayscale.
2. Invert the grayscale image to get a negative.
3. Apply a Gaussian blur to the negative from step 2.
4. Blend the grayscale image from step 1 with the blurred negative from step 3 using a colour dodge.

[Reference](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785282690/1/ch01lvl1sec10/creating-a-black-and-white-pencil-sketch)

Comment: Where does blur2 come from? It is not in your code anywhere! Or is it a typo?

Comment: @fmw42 it was a typo, I have corrected the code.

Comment: In your first code, you invert the image, blur and invert the blur. That is pretty much the same as not inverted in either place as in your second example. The two inversions negate each other.

Comment: @fmw42 I have provided the instructions in the book to convert the image to sketch. Why is the author inverting the image, if inverting it has no benefit.

Comment: Post a link to the reference.

Comment: @fmw42 I have added it.

Comment: Read the reference. If you look down further he says that they are equivalent. `A Gaussian blur is basically a convolution with a Gaussian function. One of the beauties of convolutions is their associative property. This means that it does not matter whether we first invert the image and then blur it, or first blur the image and then invert it.

"So, if we start with a blurred image and pass its inverse to the dodgeV2 function, then the image will get inverted again, essentially yielding the original image. If we get rid of these redundant operations, an optimized render method ... :`

Comment: @fmw42, I understand they are equivalent but don't you think it was redundant in the first place to introduce it.

Comment: Perhaps. But it probably was an introduced from long standing photographic equivalent techniques.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much for taking out your time.